# Django - forloop in model.py to assign foreignkey

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have two models - User and Rank. During def save() I want the Users Rank automatically assigned to a Rank depending on the points the user has and the min_points from the Rank model.

Models

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    rank = models.ForeignKey(Rank, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)


class Rank(models.Model):
    rank = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    min_points = models.IntegerField()
```

Now I added save() function to User model to check the user points and compare to the correct Rank

```
# ...user model
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    for i in Rank.objects.all():
        if self.points >= i.min_points:
            self.rank == Rank.objects.get(id=i.id)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Unfortunally nothing happend after saving or creating a new user.

My IDE throw warning:
**Unresolved attribute reference 'objects' for class 'Rank'**

Do I miss something? I cant figure out the issue...

Comment: `self.rank == Rank.objects.get(id=i.id)` will do nothing, since that only means you check equality, and regardless what you do, it does nothing with that information.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ok and how can I set the self.rank foreignkey?

Comment: with `self.rank = ...`, but you should not enumerate in the first place. You can fix this with a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to enumerate over the `Rank` objects. We can retrieve the `Rank` with the largest amount of `min_points` that is less than or equal to the `self.points` with:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.rank = Rank.objects.filter(
        min_points__lte=self.points
    ).latest('min_points')
    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works for me. You got a link where I can read more about your solution?

Comment: @Dariun: see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#latest